# How to use sed to replace every occurrence of a pattern minus one case?

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have a temporary file generated by a cron job every half hour that generates output like this:

```
---- kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<data> kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<data> kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<data>
```

I want to format it so it looks like this:

```
---- kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<data>
kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<data>
kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<data>
```

I have tried the following sed expressions:

```
sed -r 's|\s(kind=)|\n\1|g' /path/to/file
```

But then the output looks like:

```
----                                         <------ The first line should be here
kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<data>
kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<data>
kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<data>
```

Using this expression:

```
sed -r 's|[^-]{4} (kind=)|\n\1|g' /path/to/file
```

Generates the output I want, but with weird behavior:

```
---- kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<incomplete data>
kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<incomplete data>
kind=<data> field=<value> humankind=<incomplete data>
```

For some reason, the last field (which contains part of the pattern used in the sed expression) is only printing the first two characters of 'incomplete data'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `sed -r 's|\s(kind=)|\n\1|g' /path/to/file` is that you insert a new line for all ' kind' occurrences, including the first, so you get an extra newline after `----`. Instead, try

```
sed -E 's|\s(kind=)|\n\1|2g' /path/to/file
```

as it will skip the first match.

The second one fails because it matches 4 chars before ' kind', and that is part of your data (which must be 6 chars long)!

Comment: That did it! Thank you!